# Where does the -DNDEBUG normally come from?

Tags: c++, makefile, ndebug

Our build system has somehow changed such that optimized builds are no longer getting the [-DNDEBUG](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-D-1) added to the compile line.  I searched our makefiles and didn't find this.

Where does -DNDEBUG originate for most people and how might that have changed?  Before we did have -DNDEBUG, and I don't think this was removed from any of our makefiles.

Comment: may want to check your configure or configure.ac if you are using GNU build tools, i.e. autoconf and friends

Comment: I'm not using config, just GNU makefiles.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since the compiler can't decide on its own when to add the NDEBUG define and when not to, the flag is always set by either the makefile or project file (depending on your build system).

Answer (score 10):

It is really difficult to answer this since you didn't specify the build system you are using.  If you're using [Autoconf](https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=Wikipedia%20autoconf), then either the user is expected to put -DNDEBUG in CPPFLAGS manually (or perhaps you were setting it from a CONFIG_SITE file that has changed), or the *configure.ac* file might set up a custom variable for setting NDEBUG, or *configure.ac* may invoke AC_HEADER_ASSERT, in which case adding *--disable-assert* to the invocation of *[configure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configure_script)* will define NDEBUG in *config.h*.  There are lots of ways it can happen.

Comment: If I need to choose between doing `AC_DEFINE(NDEBUG,[],[])` and `CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -DNDEBUG"` in `configure.ac`, what should I do? Is it a disadvantage to have #define NDEBUG in config.h? If I do both I get lots of "NDEBUG duplicate definition" warnings that I would like to avoid.

Comment: If you are maintaining the autoconf metadata files, you should use AC_HEADER_ASSERT and let the user specify --disable-assert at configure time.  The user is responsible for ensuring that -DNDEBUG is passed to the compiler if they so desire.  It is not appropriate to define NDEBUG by default; that's not the package maintainer's prerogative.

Comment: What if -DNDEBUG is not enabled by default but by an option --enable-release? Would this be appropriate? And how would I activate -DNDEBUG in that case?

Comment: Regarding `--enable-release`, please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553735/gnu-autotools-debug-release-targets/4680578#4680578

Answer (score 5):

In my experience, -DNDEBUG has been passed manually, i.e. the makefiles have been written in such a way that the flag is passed when building in release mode.