# When does GCC define NDEBUG?

Tags: c++, gcc

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [Where does the -DNDEBUG normally come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878645/where-does-the-dndebug-normally-come-from)

I am using assertions in my code, but I don't know if they will trigger, because I don't know if NDEBUG is defined or not. Am I supposed to to specify the [-DNDEBUG](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-D-1) explicitly during compilation?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878645/where-does-the-dndebug-normally-come-from

Comment: you can also refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724569/debug-vs-release-in-cmake

Answer (score 20):

Yes. GCC by itself does not set that flag.  It is usually set by the makefile generator, like [Automake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automake), [CMake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake) or [QMake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qmake).

Comment: ... but when/how do make tools know to set `-NDEBUG`?

Comment: build targets ?

Comment: use `gcc`'s comman-line agruments