# #ifdef DEBUG with CMake independent from platform

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I am using CMake for building my projects on Windows (Visual Studio) as well as on Linux machines(gcc). I'd like to mark some code as "debugging only", like with

```
#ifdef DEBUG
//some logging here
#endif
```

The question is: what compiler definition is available on all platforms in the CMake "Debug" build type? DEBUG seems not to exist. (I want to have the logging or whatever only when the build type is Debug.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7725055/560648

Answer (score 161, accepted):

CMake adds `-DNDEBUG` to the CMAKE_C_FLAGS_{RELEASE, MINSIZEREL} by default. So, you can use `#ifndef NDEBUG`.

Comment: The double negative is nasty :)

Comment: why is there no -DDEBUG?

Comment: `NDEBUG` is one whose meaning is defined by the [C standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.2). It deactivates assertions.

Answer (score 38):

I would suggest that you add your own definition. The `CMake` symbol `CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG` can contain flags only used in debug mode. For example:

`C`:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG} -DMY_DEBUG")
```

`C++`:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -DMY_DEBUG")
```

In your code you can then write the following:

```
#ifdef MY_DEBUG
// ...
#endif
```

(Maybe, you would have to use `"/DMY_DEBUG"` for visual studio.)

Comment: I'm tempted to upvote you for your username, but instead a I downvoted because I'm not a fan of re-doing work that's already done for you by your tools, and according to the other answer, `NDEBUG` is defined by CMake, so it's preferable.

Comment: `NDEBUG` is a symbol defined by the C standard to control whether `assert()`:s should be active or not. Personally, I don't think you should use it for anything else. (Thanks for the compliment regarding the user name.)

Comment: I'm against using `NDEBUG`, as well.  FWIW, the proper way to add macro definitions (now, at least) is `add_definitions(-DMY_DEBUG)`.  The [documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_definitions.html) suggests that it recognizes `-` or `/` as prefixes, so it should be OS agnostic.

Comment: @JasonLefler, Unfortunately, using `add_definition()` won't solve the OPs problem, since it will add the definition to all configurations, not only to `Debug`.

Comment: I prefer to use NDEBUG in code and [define own assert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22140520/how-to-enable-assert-in-cmake-release-mode) (allow turn on asserts in release mode without using magic to disable NDEBUG)

Comment: @Lindydancer, You're right, I figured there'd be an `if` switch setting `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` and such or something.  To contribute something useful, then, I've confirmed that `add_definition` will parse `-` and `/`, but `set`ting the flags manually will not.

Comment: @JasonLefler, For some of the generators (including the one for Visual Studio) CMake generates one build system which contains both a Debug and a Release configuration. This mean that you can't check `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` in your CMake files. Thanks for the info on `-` and `/` in the variables!

Comment: That's CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG for C++ projects.

Comment: @KyleStrand very old, but there is a slight difference between checking NOT (Not Debug) and DEBUG, if i put critical code for debug only, i would want an OPT-IN approach and not the opposite (like off by default if no flags are defined correctly)

Answer (score 31):

In CMake >= 2.8, use [`target_compile_definitions`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_options.html):

```
target_compile_definitions(MyTarget PUBLIC "$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:DEBUG>")
```

When compiling in Debug mode, this will define the DEBUG symbol for use in your code. It will work even in IDEs like Visual Studio and Xcode for which cmake generates a single file for all compilation modes.

You have to do this for each target [1]. Alternatively you can use [`add_compile_options`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_options.html) (Cmake >= 3.0):

```
add_compile_options("$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-DDEBUG>")
```

Note that recent versions of Visual C++ (at least since VS2015) allow either / or - for parameters, so it should work fine across compilers. This command is also useful for other compile options you might like to add ("/O2" in release mode for MSVC or "-O3" for release mode in G++/Clang)

[1] : Note: in CMake >= 3.12 (currently beta) there is also an `add_compile_definitions` that supports generator expressions, which affects all targets.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following in my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(IS_DEBUG_BUILD CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")

# Indication to the code that this is a debug build
if (${IS_DEBUG_BUILD})
    add_compile_definitions(__DEBUG__)
endif ()
```

Then, in my code, I can write:

```
#ifdef __DEBUG__
    // blablabla
#edif
```

My minimum `CMake` version:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.3)
```

Comment: using identifiers beginning with double underscore `__` is not allowed

Comment: @Raildex: Well, you can use them anyway but shouldn't due to possible standard library clashes I suppose