# How to enable assert in CMake Release mode?

Tags: cmake, assert, ndebug

CMake is being used to compile some C++ files. There are `assert` calls in the code. These calls are disabled in Release mode of CMake. It defines `NDEBUG` in Release mode, I guess.

If I'm interested in having assert in Release mode of CMake, how do I enable it?

Comment: Remove this definition from `CMAKE_CXX_RELEASE_FLAGS`, obviously.

Comment: Note that if you find yourself in need to do the checks in Release, `assert` might be the wrong tool for the job (although there are still valid use cases for your question, for instance debugging a problem that only occurs in Release). Consider introducing additional diagnostic macros that have weaker semantics than assert (which de facto specifies a condition that must _never fail_) that but can still be enabled selectively (for instance, a condition that can fail if the user passes invalid arguments to a function).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### 1

If you interested in `assert` functionality only in your own code then the simple one solution
is to provide custom assert. For instance:

```
#if (MY_DEBUG)
# define MY_ASSERT(A) ... checks here ...
#else
# define MY_ASSERT(A) ... ignore A ...
#endif
```

Use `option` to enable/disable assert:

```
# CMakeLists.txt
option(ENABLE_MY_ASSERT "Turn on MY_ASSERT checks" OFF)
if(ENABLE_MY_ASSERT)
  add_definitions(-DMY_DEBUG=1)
else()
  add_definitions(-DMY_DEBUG=0)
endif()
```

In this case you have full control over your checks, you can verify one
component and ignore others:

```
... FOO_DEBUG=0 BOO_DEBUG=1 BAR_DEBUG=0 ...
```

#### 2

Add custom [CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#variable%3aCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE) (also see [CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#variable%3aCMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES)):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(foo)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MYREL "-O3")

add_library(foo foo.cpp)
```

output:

```
# Debug
# ... -g ...

# Release
# ... -O3 -DNDEBUG ...

# RelWithDebInfo
# ... -O2 -g -DNDEBUG ...

# MyRel
# ... -O3 ...
```

Answer (score 15):

See [this answer](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/FAQ#how-can-i-build-my-msvc-application-with-a-static-runtime) in the CMake FAQ, i.e.:

Fix it manually by changing the definition of the cache variables `CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE` and `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE`. This has to be done every time you set up a new build directory.

To fix it permanently, create a custom CMake rules file in your source folder with the desired settings for the release flags (omit the option `/D NDEBUG`). Then in your outermost CMakeLists.txt point the variable `CMAKE_USER_MAKE_RULES_OVERRIDE` to the custom CMake rules file.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it fixes OPs problem without changing any CMake related code.

Answer (score 15):

This would be a solution for the MSVC compiler:

```
string( REPLACE "/DNDEBUG" "" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE}")
```

A better option may be to enable asserts not in Release mode but in RelWithDebInfo mode instead:

```
string( REPLACE "/DNDEBUG" "" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO}")
```

But this depends on your project and preferences of course.

Comment: For gcc or clang, `/DNDEBUG` -> `-DNDEBUG`. To clean this up, you would have wrap it in an if statement like `if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang|GNU") ... endif()`

Comment: But why not just use the "Debug" build type then? Wouldn't that be equivalent?

Comment: It's useful when you want to apply this change only to a target, without enabling assertions in the whole project (that would also require to recompile everything)

Answer (score 7):

Here's how LLVM does it. They add a `LLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS` option to the project (change `LLVM` to your project's prefix), then check for it and filter the compile flags. There is a special case for MSVC.

Overall, this seems more sensible to me than defining a build configuration. Enabling assertions is IMO orthogonal concern to the overall build configuration.

```
# This is commonly needed so define it before we include anything else.
string(TOUPPER "${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}" uppercase_CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)

[...]

if(uppercase_CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "DEBUG" )
    option(QD_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS "Enable assertions" ON)
else()
    option(QD_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS "Enable assertions" OFF)
endif()

[...]

if(QD_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS)
    if(NOT MSVC)
        add_definitions(-D_DEBUG)
    endif()
    # On non-Debug builds cmake automatically defines NDEBUG, so we explicitly undefine it:
    if(NOT uppercase_CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "DEBUG")
        # NOTE: use `add_compile_options` rather than `add_definitions` since
        # `add_definitions` does not support generator expressions.
        add_compile_options($<$<OR:$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:C>,$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CXX>>:-UNDEBUG>)

        # Also remove /D NDEBUG to avoid MSVC warnings about conflicting defines.
        foreach (flags_var_to_scrub
                CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE
                CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
                CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
                CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE
                CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
                CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL)
            string (REGEX REPLACE "(^| )[/-]D *NDEBUG($| )" " "
                    "${flags_var_to_scrub}" "${${flags_var_to_scrub}}")
        endforeach()
    endif()
endif()
```

Source: https://opensource.apple.com/source/llvmCore/llvmCore-2358.3/CMakeLists.txt.auto.html

Comment: The foreach block should be moved outside the CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE check block. Apart from that, it works well.

Comment: Why is that the case?

Comment: For MSVC (default generator with msbuild), CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE is generally not specified at configure time. The configuration is chosen at make time. Putting the foreach block inside the CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE does not seem useful to me. (However, it does not harm too much, for generally people do not specified CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE, so the "NOT" condition is still satisfied generally.)