# Eigen matrix size assertion for cmake "release" mode

Tags: cmake, eigen

In Eigen, it appears the assertion that checks for matrix sizes for matrix multiplication is disabled by default when using a release mode of the cmake. Is there anyway to keep this assertion when using the release mode ?

I have a matrix product `m1*m2` in my code where the `m1.cols() != m2.rows()`. Both matrix are of dynamic size. When I `set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)` Eigen will check the size of the matrices and throws an error. When I `set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)` the size check gets disabled and the evaluation `m1*m2` goes through, accessing out of bounds memory and the result is almost random.

Answer (score 1):

To make use of `assert` in release mode, you must undefine the `NDEBUG` macro. Take a look at the suggestions [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22140520/how-to-enable-assert-in-cmake-release-mode).

However, I would not recommend this. It would enable `assert` calls in release mode all over the code you are building. It kind of breaks the contract for the `NDEBUG` macro. And if you are unlucky it may also affect performance.

If that specific assertion/test is important for you, add it yourself at the application level of your code using something other than `assert`.

Answer (score 0):

You can predefine `eigen_assert` before including any Eigen headers, e.g., making it `throw` (or `cerr` and `terminate`).

```
#define eigen_assert(cond) if(!(cond)) {throw std::runtime_error(#cond);}
#include <Eigen/Core>

int main()
{
    assert(false && "not triggered in release mode");
    Eigen::Matrix3d A;
    Eigen::MatrixXd B(3,2);
    A+=B;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Rqz7BB