# not able to get correct source path in gdb

Tags: debugging, gdb, cmake, midori

I have a project checked out from `midori` repository. I want to debug the project using gdb after build but when I tried to put breakpoint on a source file, gdb doesn't identify that.

This is my Cmakelist.txt file https://github.com/shashwat001/midori-modified/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt.

As instructed here http://midori-browser.org/contribute/#build_the_code . I created _build folder and from inside that I run `cmake` and then `make`.
Then the executable to run midori was `_build/midori/midori`.

From source folder, I run

```
gdb _build/midori/midori
```

Then put breakpoint to file midori/midori-panel.c

```
break midori/midori-panel.c:350
```

Then following error was shown: `No source file midori-panel.c`

Do I need to make any change to Cmake file to enable that or I need some other syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build your binary in debug mode. See [example 1](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2008-March/020347.html) and [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7725055/50617).

```
cd build/your_project/debug;
cmake path_to_project_srcs -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG
```