# Modifying variables in cmake-gui

Tags: c++, cmake, cmake-gui

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724569/debug-vs-release-in-cmake) is said that to run cmake for each builds (debug and release) it is recommended to pass `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` as an argument to `cmake`, e.g. `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..` or `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..` What is the equivalent of this in cmake-gui? When I press "Configure" then some variables pops-up in window and here I will create new one `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` and then press "Generate" is this equivalent of above mentioned command line passing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It is equivalent.

Note that [CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html) only works for single-configuration generators like Unix Makefiles. Generators like Visual Studio generate multi-configuration projects and the choice of the one being compiled is done in the IDE.

**EDIT:** As stated in comments, and unlike what I suggested below, `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is not an advanced variable, and effectively needs to be added in the GUI.

Not sure, but `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` may already exists as an advanced option: check the "Advanced" checkbox in the GUI to show all the variables.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. FYI: CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE is not available under "Advanced". I've also tried to pass -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Debug" to cmake-gui but seems that it does not recognize it and only way is to modify variables from GUI. Your note about single-configurations and multi-configurations shines a light to my another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401044/proper-way-to-compile-project-with-debug-symbols-and-cmake

Comment: Thank you again. Also comes to my mind that e.g. `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` is probably useless when Visual Studio is used as configuration generator. Are there some list of variables that should be avoided e.g. for Visual Studio? Thank you.

Comment: `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` is not useless when Visual Studio is used as configuration generator: it is used by the `INSTALL` project generated with the solution. AFAIK There is no real list of the variables unused by the Visual Studio generator. Variables related to Unix or OSX are de facto useless for Visual for examples, but they will just be ignored during generation so there is no reason to avoid them at all