# Proper way to compile project with debug symbols and cmake

Tags: cmake, cmake-gui, libharu

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724569/debug-vs-release-in-cmake) is recommended to pass `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` as an argument to cmake when I want to obtain debug or release project builds. I'm trying to compile [libharu](http://libharu.org/) with cmake and I would like to compile it with debug symbols. I've searched CMakeLists.txt included in [libharu](http://libharu.org/) for following strings:

```
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG
```

but I've found nothing. My question is that if it does make any sense to specify `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` when [libharu](http://libharu.org/)'s CMakeLists.txt doesn't mention it? If not, how can I compile [libharu](http://libharu.org/) with debug symbols?

PS: I've noticed that project that was generated for Visual Studio 2013 with cmake had set Debug/Win32, is this sufficient? Where in CMakeLists.txt is specified this info?

PPS: I guess this question is highly depending on particular project but is there some way to do this in general? I mean, does `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` always create Debug build or is there something else that I should be aware of?

Thanks

Comment: I would say that changing CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE any way except for by passing directly to cmake should be avoided.  However, for this library, what happened when you set CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE to Debug?  Did it compile with debug symbols? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999654/how-can-i-tell-if-a-library-was-compiled-with-g

Comment: @RobertPrévost seems that it is already compiled with it, at least pdb file was created. Is there way to check if current build is created with debug symbols?

Comment: There seems to be a few different ways to check how the library was built (e.g., if it was compiled /mt or /mtd)  and many questions on SO about that.  A pdb file does certainly help debugging.  From microsoft: "A program database (.pdb) file, also called a symbol file, maps the identifiers that you create in source files for classes, methods, and other code to the identifiers that are used in the compiled executables of your project."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting configuration type via `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` switches set of additional options for compiler to one, which *normally* reflects meaning of the configuration. That is, passing

```
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
```

to `cmake` tells compiler to generate debugging information **unless CMakeLists.txt modifies that behavior**.

Config-dependent compiler options are contained in variables `CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS_<CONFIG>`. For example, variable `CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG` contains additional options for C compiler in "Debug" configuration. These variables are filled by CMake automatically, and `CMakeLists.txt` itself rare modifies them.

So, if you found that `CMakeLists.txt` doesn't play with variables `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` and `CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS_<CONFIG>`, then *it follows common conventions about configuration type*.

---

This **doesn't mean** that `CMakeLists.txt` **shouldn't play** with that variables.

Often `CMakeLists.txt` sets `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` to some default value, provided the variable is not set by the user and single-config generator is used. `CMakeLists.txt` also may set some of variables `CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS_<CONFIG>`, if default setting for compiler is not suited for the project.

But even if `CMakeLists.txt` does not touch these variables, they work.

Comment: Tank you for answer. If I understand correct then well written `CMakeLists.txt` should not mess with `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` and `CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS_<CONFIG>` and passing those variables via `-D` is correct way?

Comment: `well written CMakeLists.txt should not mess with CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE and CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS_<CONFIG>` - Not quite true. I mean that event if `CMakeLists.txt` does not touch them, they works in expected manner. See updated answer.