# why specifying architecture needs to be done in cmake for multi-configuration generators

Tags: cmake, cpu-architecture, cmake-gui, multi-configuration

I understand that `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` only works for single-configuration generators like Unix Makefiles. There are also multi-configuration generators like Visual Studio or Xcode where `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` does not works. (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24460486/cmake-build-type-not-being-used-in-cmakelists-txt) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401026/modifying-variables-in-cmake-gui) question for further info). I've generated Visual Studio 2013 x86 project with cmake-gui for [libharu](http://libharu.org/) and there is not possible to switch from win32 to x64 in Visual Studio. I'm wondering why in multi-configurations it is need to specify architecture (x86 or x64) in cmake? Why it is not possible in Visual Studio directly? Is there some limitation or benefit or something that I should be aware of?

Thanks

Comment: It's a cmake limitation and also kind of intentional. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334095/cmake-multiarchitecture-compilation it is mentioned that cmake wants different build directories per compiler and 32 and 64-bit compilations are seen as with different compilers/compiler environment. Also cmake encourages out-of-source builds so you cannot unify 64 and 32 in a VS with that philisophy.

Comment: @Hayt thanks for reply, please post it as an answer an I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this switch between 32 and 64 bit is not available in all environments cmake follows the philosophy to use out-of-source builds and have each compiler in their own directory. So a 32 bit and a 64 bit build can be seen as a a different compilation environment so they each generate their own folders.

So while this is a cmake limitation it is also intentional.

This answer also mentions this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5359191/152359