# Profile OpenCV with sprof

Tags: c++, cmake, profiling, gprof, sprof

I have this basic OpenCV code:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

int main(){
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("/home/luca/Documents/IMG_20161031_162242.jpg", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    if(!img.data)
        std::cerr<<"Error reading image"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I want to profile it to make `cv::imread` parallel (and try to do the same with many other functions.

Reading [this](http://greg-n-blog.blogspot.it/2010/01/profiling-shared-library-on-linux-using.html) article, what I should do for time profiling a shared-library (as opencv in my case) I should:

> 1) Compile your shared library (libmylib.so) in debug (-g) mode. No
>   -pg. 2) export LD_PROFILE_OUTPUT=`pwd` 3) export LD_PROFILE=libmylib.so 4) rm -f $LD_PROFILE.profile 4) execute your
>   program that loads libmylib.so 5) sprof PATH-TO-LIB/$LD_PROFILE
>   $LD_PROFILE.profile -p >log 6) See the log.

I have some questions:

1. How do I now which shared library calls `cv::imread`?
2. I don't know if `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG ...` includes `-g` (actually I don't think so). Reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7725055/4480180) I could do this by editing `CMakeLists.txt` with:

`set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -g")`

But I don't know where to set it in `CMakeLists.txt`

Comment: 'Debug' usually implies compiling with debug information, that is `-g` is normally included in that configuration. `How do I now which shared library calls cv::imread?` - Do you mean which library **defines** `cv::imread`? It is your executable which *calls* the function.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks for your comment. Yes, I mean how do I know which library defines a certain function (it was 2am when I've posted the question :) )

Comment: have You tried [nm](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/nm.html)?