# Valgrind not showing line numbers when compiled with cmake

Tags: c, debugging, cmake, valgrind

I am compiling my project with the command `cmake .. -G "CodeBlocks - Ninja`, which works fine, but when I run valgrind it does not display any lines numbers.
This is the valgrind command I am using: `valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --track-origins=yes  --log-file="log.txt" ./pony_gpExe`.

Here is an example of the output:

```
==5402== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==5402==    at 0x40447B: get_double_arr_length (in /home/robbie/Dropbox/MIT/pony_gp_ubuntu/build/pony_gpExe)
==5402==    by 0x405184: get_test_and_train_data (in /home/robbie/Dropbox/MIT/pony_gp_ubuntu/build/pony_gpExe)
==5402==    by 0x4027B3: setup (in /home/robbie/Dropbox/MIT/pony_gp_ubuntu/build/pony_gpExe)
==5402==    by 0x402861: main (in /home/robbie/Dropbox/MIT/pony_gp_ubuntu/build/pony_gpExe)
==5402==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==5402==    at 0x405149: get_test_and_train_data (in /home/robbie/Dropbox/MIT/pony_gp_ubuntu/build/pony_gpExe)
```

Not sure if this is helpful but here is my main CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.3)
project (pony_gp)
set(DIR ${pony_gp_SOURCE_DIR})

file(GLOB_RECURSE pony_gp_SOURCES "${DIR}/src/*.c")
file(GLOB_RECURSE pony_gp_HEADERS "${DIR}/include/*.h")

foreach (_headerFile ${pony_gp_HEADERS})
    get_filename_component(_dir ${_headerFile} PATH)
    list (APPEND pony_gp_INCLUDE_DIRS ${_dir})
endforeach()
list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES pony_gp_INCLUDE_DIRS)

include("${DIR}/include/CMakeLists.txt")
include_directories(${pony_gp_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable (pony_gpExe ${pony_gp_SOURCES})

if (CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC)

    target_link_libraries(pony_gpExe m)

    find_program(MEMORYCHECK_COMMAND valgrind)
    set(MEMORYCHECK_COMMAND_OPTIONS "--trace-children=yes --leak-check=full")
    set(MEMORYCHECK_SUPPRESSIONS_FILE "${DIR}/valgrind_suppress.txt")
endif()

include(CTest)
add_test(test pony_gpExe)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell `cmake` to produce a debug executable. Without seeing your cmake config, it's hard to tell you how to do this, but by default/convention, it should be:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
```

See this answer on [Debug vs Release in CMAKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724569/debug-vs-release-in-cmake) for additional infomation.

Comment: I added this, but it didn't fix it. What should I include to give a clear picture of my cmake config? The CmakeLists.txt?

Comment: Yes, start there. I'm not very familiar with cmake, I'm afraid.

Comment: This worked for me and was the only change I needed to have valgrind show me line numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you compiled your code with `-g` and assume you running code in `Ubuntu` or `Mac OS`

Try to run `valgrind` like this which does the trick in Ubuntu

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --track-origins=yes --dsymutil=yes --log-file="log.txt" ./pony_gpExe.
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't fix it. And yes, I am running this on Ubuntu.

Comment: It just prints the output of my program.

Comment: Did you builded like `cmake -G Ninja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried typing that in exactly yet it still didn't solve anything.

Answer (score 0):

So, I don't know why but randomly valgrind started to show the line numbers... I didn't really do anything different, but either way it works...