# LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'python37_d.lib'

Tags: python, c++

I was trying to integrate Python interpreter in C++ application in Visual Studio 2013, despite of adding INCLUDES and ENV VARIABLES such as LIB & LIBPATH, compilation is throwing an Error as

LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'python37_d.lib'.

I tried all possible google suggestions, but still I am not able get rid of this Error. Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What are your settings for library path and include path as well as the libraries to link?

Comment: Hi,Settings are as below:                                                                           Include Path: (Proporties->Configuration Properties->VC++ Directories->Include Directories)
C:\Users\Shridhar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include -----> This is where Python37 resides

Library Path:(Proporties->Configuration Properties->VC++ Directories->Libraries Directories)
C:\Users\Shridhar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\libs -----> libraries folder

Comment: Cool, and what does it say for "additional dependencies?"

Comment: Here's the obvious question, do you have a file called C:\Users\Shridhar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\libs\python37_d.lib? Because your linker is telling you that you don't.

Comment: @john On my machine in the same folder for python 36 I just have python36.lib and python3.lib

Answer (score 7):

This library is intended for debugging, and you simply don't have it if the Python was installed with default options. To obtain it, you are to (re)install Python with "Download debug binaries" option enabled in the installer. Then the `python37_d.lib` will be located in `%PythonPath%\Libs` together with `python3_d.lib`.

Comment: I am wondering, how visual studio determined to require this library for compilation, given that I didn't explicit ask for it.

Comment: The same way as many other libraries do: using the preprocessor. Search `include\pyconfig.h` for `pragma comment(lib,"python37_d.lib")` line (#274 in Python3.7). For MSVC consult the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/preprocessor/comment-c-cpp?view=msvc-160).

Comment: I see. So libraries are only specified through command-line options, but can also be requested in header files.

Answer (score 0):

Following up the Suthiro's answer, you can also explicitly specify `Debug` or `Release` configurations for multi-configuration generators (Ninja Multi-Config, Visual Studio) by running

```
# Configure the build
cmake -S . -B build

# Actually build the binaries
cmake --build build --config Release
```

in your source directory.
For single configuration generators and more details see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64719718/15452880.