# Select CMake's release mode from command line on any platform

Tags: cmake

I'm looking to set CMake's release mode from the command-line *on any platform*. I found e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724569/debug-vs-release-in-cmake) that the details are slightly different on the different platforms. But to simplify CI-setup I'm looking to execute the same command on Unix *and* Windows. I tried:

```sh
cmake . -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE
cmake --build .
```

But then I get on Windows:

```sh
Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

   CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE
```

Is it even possible? If so, what should I use?

Comment: Thank @Tsyvarev , that is a clear answer. It's a petty though that is seems impossible, it would be so nice to have one set of commands to run everywhere...

Comment: @Tsyvarev that would make a good answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a distinction between Linux and Windows. This is a distinction between **single-configuration** and **multi-configuration** [generators](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html).

CMake uses different specification of "build type" when configure and build a project for different type of generators:

1. With a **single-configuration** generator (e.g. "Unix Makefiles") build type is specified on **configuration** stage using `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` variable:

   ```
   cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release <source-dir>
   cmake --build .
   ```
2. With a **multi-configuration** generator (e.g. Visual Studio) build type is not known on *configuration* stage: this stage is performed for several build types at once. When **build** the project, one need to select appropriate build type, e.g. using `--config` option:

   ```
   cmake <source-dir>
   cmake --build . --config Release
   ```

Because build type is specified on different stages, single set of commands rarely exists for both generator types.

However, single set of commands is perfectly possible in case of selecting generator "Unix Makefiles" on Linux and generator "NMake Makefiles" on Windows: both these generators are *single-configuration*.

Comment: I think point 2 is missing the directory after --build

I got error `Error: /somepath/--config is not a directory` until I ran:
`cmake --build . --config Release`

Comment: @PeterNimmo: Yes, the option '--build' requires a value, thanks for the point. The answer is fixed now.