# CMake --config since version 3.20

Tags: cmake

All the build hierarchy of my project is based on `ExternalProject` with `--config` option. A few days ago I updated to CMake 3.20, and now `--config` is gone:

```
$ cmake --config
CMake Error: Unknown argument --config
CMake Error: Run 'cmake --help' for all supported options.
```

While the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/build_command.html) [still advises](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/index.html) to use it, and the [Release notes](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/release/3.20.html) is also silent about the option.

What should I use instead of `--config`?

Answer (score 3):

You should use for configure:

```
cmake -S . -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

`CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` will be ignored at configure

And for build:

```
cmake --build . --config Release
```

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/64719718
I don't understand why docs ignored this movement

Comment: That is not the same.

CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE is valid for generators like GNU Make or Ninja which can only build one type per build folder.

Meanwhile --config is for generators like XCode or Visual Studio which ignore CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE and toggle between Debug/Release at runtime

Comment: Yep, it's not the same but you can use it this way

Answer (score 2):

OK I had the same problem on macOS with the XCode generator.

Turns out all I was missing was the `--build` command.

i.e. instead of:

`cmake . --config Debug`

I have to type:

`cmake --build . --config Debug`

Answer (score 0):

Based on [github Issue](https://github.com/udacity/CppND-Route-Planning-Project/issues/36) you should use

```sh
cmake --build .
```

Comment: `--build` is another option which has nothing to do with build configuration specification. It's already used by `ExternalProject_Add` commands together with `--config`. The given solution probably solves the problem of that paticular project (udacity), but does not answer my question.

Comment: I don't face this problem. I hope solve this problem and thanks for your comment @Sergey If you reach a correct answer ,I will share with you.