# How to know whether it is doing a debug or release build in Flutter Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, flutter, dart, cmake

I have some Python scripts which should run when building the Flutter Windows app. It looks like:

```
find_package( PythonInterp 3 REQUIRED )
add_custom_target(
 myscript ALL
 COMMAND ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} somefile.py
)
add_dependencies(${PLUGIN_NAME} myscript)
```

However, in my script, I need to know whether it is doing a debug or a release build. But I cannot find out an approach to do this.

I have tried to print every cmake variable, and nothing indicates it is a debug or release. I have also tried to print out all environment variables in the python script, but again nothing interesting.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: On single-config generators [`CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html) should have it.

Comment: @ixSci Though I have found the answer https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/99595 Thanks all the same

Comment: Why the c++ tag?

Comment: @AnoopRana flutter has a bit of c++ code as glue

Comment: @ch271828n Yes i am aware of that but so does many other things that are not directly related to the question that you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Debug vs Release in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724569/debug-vs-release-in-cmake)

Answer (score 0):

In https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/99595, @stuartmorgan provides a good answer, so I paste it here in case someone needs it:

> There is nothing special about the CMake builds used in the Flutter template; determining the build type is done in the usual way.

And that "usual way" is https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#build-configurations :

```
# Works correctly for both single and multi-config generators
target_compile_definitions(exe1 PRIVATE
  $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:DEBUG_BUILD>
)
```