Decreasing size of built LLVM binaries
I'm trying to link against LLVM from Rust using the llvm-sys crate. The problem is, linking against all of LLVM 18.1 using the default build flags results in a 4.8 GB rlib, which has the SYM32 symbol table and isn't supported, meaning I have to lower the binary size below 4GB. I tried disabling the low hanging fruit like LLVM examples, benchmarks, etc... in the build, but since I'm only linking against libs that changed nothing. The build is in release mode, so it isn't debug symbols inflating the build, just following the default LLVM build steps with no other projects enabled. Is there something I'm doing majorly wrong to cause this?

You're probably using static linking? If you don't have a strong reason for that you might want try linking to libLLVM.so

This build is on Windows, LLVM is super weird with dynamic linking on Windows

To clarify-- LLVM doesn't support building dynamic libraries on windows, nor does it support linking against them on windows (llvm-config fails).

The build is in release mode Did you try MinSizeRel mode instead?

@jpr42 I thought that MinSizeRel wasn't changing anything, until I realized that the build action was uploading nothing and never updating the build file and indeed MinSizeRel may be the solution. If you want the reputation, feel free to write it as an answer

Try building with MinSizeRel instead of Release mode.
cmake ... -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=MinSizeRel --fresh
cmake --build ... --config MinSizeRel --clean-first
cmake --install ... --config MinSizeRel


Not only was it MinSizeRel, but it was missing the --config args too! I'm not sure how the packages I was looking at built correctly without it

Depends on the generator you are using. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64719718/19739129

Since you are on Windows you are likely using the Visual Studio generator which is why you need to use --config.

At a guess: You want cmake -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=X86
LLVM supports a lot of targets, and when I started with LLVM I got full support for every target, which involved similarly large files and building LLVM was sloooow, too. Telling LLVM that I only wanted to build for a single CPU helped. I'm guessing that you want just a single CPU, and that the CPU you want is the miserable Intel thing.
