# C++ How do I operate in debug mode with macro debug defined?

Tags: c++, debugging, cygwin

I am using cygwin to compile my program. The command I use is g++ -std=c++11 -W -Wall -pedantic a1.cpp

I want to execute a part of code if debug mode is defined and another part if not.

My question is, what is that command to compile in debug mode and what should I put inside my code for the if/else execution?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290509/debug-vs-ndebug

Comment: Note that you will find it hard to debug the code that is not executed in debug mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a command line option define like `-DDEBUGMODE` to your debug builds.

In your code you could decide what to do depending on `DEBUGMODE` being defined or not.

```
#ifdef DEBUGMODE
    //DEBUG code
#else
    //RELEASE code
#endif
```

I would also recommend to read
[_DEBUG vs NDEBUG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290509/debug-vs-ndebug)
and
[Where does the -DNDEBUG normally come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1878645/4181011)

Answer (score 0):

1- First debugging enable/disable method is to add -D  to your completion command, like this:

```
gcc -D DEBUG <prog.c>
```

2- Second: To enable debugging define the MACRO that is replaced with a debugging statement like this:

```
#define DEBUG(fmt, ...) fprintf(stderr, fmt,__VA_ARGS__);
```

To disable debugging define The MACRO to be replaced with nothing like this:

```
#define DEBUG(fmt, ...)
```

Example ready to be debugged :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int addNums(int a, int b)
{
DEBUG ("add the numbers: %d and %d\n", a,b)
return a+b;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int arg1 =0, arg2 = 0 ;

if (argc > 1)
  arg1 = atoi(argv[1]);
  DEBUG ("The first argument is : %d\n", arg1)

if (argc == 3)
  arg2 = atoi(argv[2]);
  DEBUG ("The second argument is : %d\n", arg2)


printf("The sum of the numbers is %d\n", addNums(arg1,arg2) );

return (0);
}
```